# Core Data, userID takes another value every time when the same login email address and password for logging in?

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

In this code, first we will check the email address and password from Core Data Object. If it exists then it goes to next View Controller with their UserID. If the email address and password doesn't exist in the Core database, then it first save these details in the core data object and then goto next view controller.   But my issue is when i add detail for the first time in the databse then it takes UserId = 1, when i again login with the same email address and password, now it takes UserId = 2. Please resolve this issue. I am new to CoreData.

```
 import UIKit
import CoreData

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var tfEmail: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var tfPwd: UITextField!

    var lastsaved_UID2: Bool = false

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

    }

@IBAction func btnLogin(_ sender: Any)
    {
        if tfEmail.text != "" && tfPwd.text != ""
        {

            if lastsaved_UID2 == false && user.count != 0
            {
                print("Check Email Address and Pwd from Local DB")
                for i in 0..<(user.count)
                {
                    let usr = user[i]

                    if tfEmail.text == usr.email && tfPwd.text == usr.password
                    {
                        lastSavedUID = usr.id
                        print("Login and when it has some objects : \(lastSavedUID)")

                        let vc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "VisitorData") as! VisitorData
                        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
                        return
                    }

                }
                return

            }
            else
            {
                print("False Email Address and Pwd from Local DB")
                lastsaved_UID2 = true
            }



            if lastsaved_UID2 == true
            {
                print("Entered Here")
                    if user.count == 0
                    {
                        lastSavedUID = 1
                        User.saveData(strPwd: self.tfPwd.text!, strEmail: self.tfEmail.text!, id: lastSavedUID)

                        let vc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "VisitorData") as! VisitorData
                        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
                    }
                    else {
                        let usr = user[user.count - 1]
                        let lastObectUID = Int16(usr.id)
                        let savedID = lastObectUID + 1

                        //Save Data
                        User.saveData(strPwd: self.tfPwd.text!, strEmail: self.tfEmail.text!, id: savedID)
                        lastSavedUID = savedID
                        print("Not Login and when it has some objects : \(lastSavedUID)")

                        let vc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "VisitorData") as! VisitorData
                        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
                    }
            }

        }


        else {
            let alert = UIAlertController.init(title: "", message: "Please enter email and password", preferredStyle: .alert)
            alert.addAction(UIAlertAction.init(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: nil))
            present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }

    }
```

Comment: There's some issue with { and } in your code, could you just copy from your Xcode complete btnLogin() method?

Comment: Why do you repeat this code in different cases?
  if tfEmail.text == usr.email && tfPwd.text == usr.password
                        {
                            lastSavedUID = usr.id
                            print("Login and when it has some objects : \(lastSavedUID)")

                            let vc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "VisitorData") as! VisitorData
                            self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
                        }

Comment: for saving UserId in different cases

Comment: but case is the same:
tfEmail.text == usr.email && tfPwd.text == usr.password

Comment: can you plz elaborate ?

Comment: Your code doesn't compile and doesn't makes sense because the number of { and } doesn't match. Did you make some mistake copying the code? As @AntonNovoselov said replace the code in your question with the one you have in Xcode.

Comment: i changed it...

Comment: You should completely refactor your code. It's hard to tell from what to begin with.. Could you upload your whole project to some cloud service and provide link here?

Answer (score 0):

You have a property lastSavedUID (not clear where it's defined) that you use to save the last id for inserting but never use when a new user is saved which is strange, instead you look at some user array to find a new id. Is this array sorted correctly and is it updated for each added user?

I would change the following code

```
let usr = user[user.count - 1]
let lastObectUID = Int16(usr.id)
let savedID = lastObectUID + 1
```

with

```
 lastSavedUID = lastSavedUID + 1
 let saveID = lastSavedUID
```